# AngularJS directive with iconify icons do not respond to scope variable changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, icons

I am in the process of converting an app to use iconify (https://iconify.design/) over from including the entire font-awesome CSS. Should be a simple task, right? Except I've run into an issue where icons inside a directive do not get updated on scope changes.

I initially thought I could just do

```
<i class="iconify" data-icon="{{ my_value }}"></i>
```

per the suggestions at https://iconify.design/docs/icon-aliases/, and switch out my_value as needed. But that didn't work (even outside of a directive). So I tried with two icons, ng-showing them via my_value:

```
<i class="iconify" data-icon="this" ng-show="my_value == 'this'"></i>
<i class="iconify" data-icon="that" ng-show="my_value == 'that'"></i>
```

But likewise that has no effect - and now the issue seems confined to when the icon placeholders do appear inside a directive.

Plnkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/7on7CXuaCOUcMsCmQ8rd?p=preview

I'm guessing this has something to do with .. no, actually I have no ideas. So how can I make what seems like a common enough task, work?

Answer (score 2):

Move the `ng-show` directives to elements that enclose the icon element:

```
<div>
  <h3>Eye does not toggle (in directive)</h3>
  <button ng-click="style = (style == 'fa-eye' ? 'fa-eye-slash': 'fa-eye')">
    Click
  </button>
  (style is [{{ style }}])
  <br /> Control: <i class="iconify icon:fa-eye"></i>
  <br /> Should toggle:

  <span ng-show="style == 'fa-eye'"> 
     <i class="iconify icon:fa-eye"></i>
  </span>
  <span ng-show="style == 'fa-eye-slash'">
     <i class="iconify icon:fa-eye-slash"></i>
  </span>

</div>
```

The Iconify software is replacing the `<i>` element with an `<svg>` element.
This results in the `ng-show` directives being destroyed.

It works if the `ng-show` directives are placed on a parent element.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/LeakbdMdFTslze8YjoXm?p=preview)

Comment: *facepalm* laughably simple! Although it seems like a non-solution, it works, and I can make progress.